# Хранение параметров с разными типами данных в одной таблице

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, eav, модель-данных

Есть набор параметров с разными типами данных. У каждого параметра есть имя, набор ещё каких-то свойств и само значение параметра. Эта значение параметра может быть разных типов в зависимости самого параметра.

**Вопрос:** Как организовать хранение значений этих параметров в одной таблице?

**Варианты которые сразу пришли в голову:**

1. Хранить значение параметра в типа varchar и сделать ещё один столбец с описанием типа. И в случае необходимости этого параметра в приложении конвертировать его в нужный тип. Таблица с параметрами выглядела бы примерно так:

   `id | name | value | value_type`
2. Сделать кучу полей на каждый существующий тип параметра. То есть таблица с параметрами выглядела бы примерно так:

   `id | name | value_varchar | value_int | value_bit | и так далее`

Какие best practice есть для решения задачи такого рода?

**Уточнение задачи:**

1. Разумеется это будет две таблицы. Одна таблица-справочник с идентификатором и именем параметра, а другая таблица-связь параметра с другой сущностью.
2. Параметров этих будет не много. Не много в рамках БД конечно. Не 2 миллиона.
3. Использоваться это будет следующим образом: Будет хранимка которая получает набор параметров по идентификатору той самой другой сущности. И в приложении мне нужно их распарсить в плане типа и использовать. Если это какой-то размер, то конвертируем в int или double и применять. Если это какое-то название, то конвертируем в string и используем, и так далее.

**Принятое решение:** Использовать тип данных [`sql_variant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173829(v=sql.120).aspx).

Comment: думаю 3 колонок varchar, date или как он в ms-sql и int достаточно, остальные приводятся к ним

Comment: @Mike Как я понял ты советуешь использовать мой 2-й вариант и ограничиться 3-мя полями. Строка, число и дата. Верно?

Comment: Да, я бы так сделал. пихать даты и числа в varchar может боком выйти. в одном запросе захочешь выбрать несколько параметров, столбиком и какую нибудь функцию получения даты или числа из строки напишешь, а на части записей они будут ругаться, что данные не подходят им, придется кучу костылей забивать

Comment: Вообще хочется чуть подробнее понять задачу. какие у "параметра" могут быть еще атрибуты кроме имени, что это за параметры такие. И хранение имени параметра прямо в этой таблицы то же как то криво. обычно все таки делают справочник возможных параметров отдельно. Что бы обеспечить как минимум уникальность имен параметров, да и тип данных что бы у параметра с одним именем был всегда один и тот же. Хотя может у вас задача какая то экзотическая ...

Comment: Присоединяюсь к _хочется чуть подробнее понять задачу_. Думаю, что best practices будет зависеть от того, что в дальнейшем вы собираетесь делать с этими данными. В частности, будут ли по ним "тяжёлые" запросы, или данные будут доставаться небольшими кусочками.

Comment: @i-one Уточнил задачу

Comment: Если вам и правда нужно хранить набор данных, не описывающийся одной схемой, то возможно, реляционная база данных вам просто не подходит.

Comment: Есть тип поля json. Даст гораздо больше преимуществ.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich Я думал и про XML и про JSON, но почему-то они меня не очень устроили.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В MS SQL Server, начиная с версии 2008, есть такой тип данных, как [`sql_variant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173829(v=sql.120).aspx). Это именно то, что нужно вам в вашей задаче.

Comment: Да. Походу это то что нужно. А в приложении в нужных местах буду конвертировать определенные параметры в нужный мне тип данных. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Если использовать первый вариант, то я бы навесил ограничение на столбец value. Ограничение, использующее функцию, которая на вход принимает значение value_type и проверяет соответствие значения типу с помощью встроенных функций типа isdate(), isnumeric().

Comment: Отличный совет. Спасибо. Благотворно скажется на целостности данных.

Answer (score 1):

Ознакомьтесь с описанием объектной модели хранения данных в РСУБД.

Возможно будет полезно.

[БД - хранилище объектов](http://compress.ru/article.aspx?id=11515)

Кратко о чем там применительно к вопросу.

Для каждого типа свойств создаётся пара таблиц:
Строковые:

Strings(TypeId, ObjectId, Value); StringDesc(TypeId, Code, ItemName)

временные, числовые и.т.п по аналогии

```
Strings - собственно значения свойств
StringDesc - описание типов свойств

значения столбцов:
ObjectId - ид объекта
TypeId - ид типа свойства
Code - код свойства
ItemName - человеческое описание свойства
Value - значение свойства.
```

Пусть объекты хранятся в таблице Objects(Id, TypeId, ItemName)
тогда можно писать запросы наподобие:

```
SELECT O.ItemName, S.Value
   FROM Objects O
    INNER JOIN ObjType OT ON O.TypeId = OT.Id
    INNER JOIN Strings S ON O.Id = S.ObjectId
    INNER JOIN StrDesc SD ON S.TypeId = SD.Id
  WHERE OT.Code = ‘EMPLOYEE’
    AND SD.TypeId = OT.Id
    AND SD.Code = ‘EMAIL’
```

Плюсы этого подхода в том, что изменяя данные в БД - мы меняем структуру объектов, не меняя структуру таблиц.
Минусы - вертикальное хранение атрибутов и всё, что с этим связано.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил. Кратко описал применительно к вопросу.

Comment: Создавать кучу таблиц на разные типы параметров не очень удобно. Если у меня будут свойства, допустим для начала, 3-х типов (строка, целое число и дата), то это уже +6 таблиц и портянки с запросами. Возможно в какой-то ситуации этот вариант будет отлично смотреться. Но в моем случае мне хотелось бы обойтись двумя таблицами: Справочником свойств, и связями свойств с каким-то конкретным объектом. Я пока обошелся типом sql_variant. То есть значения свойств храню именно в этом типе.

Answer (score 0):

**Я бы использовал 1-й вариант.**

Я не знаю, какая тематика базы данных, но осмелюсь предположить, что большинство параметров будут `varchar`, `char`, `nvarchar`. Так что если сделать поле `value` в типа `varchar` с большим значением, то можно будет хранить абсолютно любые данные.

- Для выборки данных другого типа вполне можно использоваться функции `CAST()` и `CONVERT()`.
  И то они понадобятся только если надо проводить (например)
  математические операции над цифрами. А если не надо, то `value = '1'`
  тоже работать будет. Или даты сравнивать...
- Если `value` заиндексировать, то и `LIKE()` будет достаточно быстро работать

Еще мне кажется, что в таком случае `value_type` не нужно. Все равно ведь при построении запросов Вы будете знать, какие данные будут обрабатываться, и будете применять нужный `CAST()`.

---

**2-й вариант, конечно тоже приемлим**

Однако, по-моему, мешает то, что типов данных в MsSQL много (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx).
Да, их можно сгруппировать и хранить, скажем `int`, `smallint` и `numeric` в одной колонке. Но даже в этом случае понадобятся от 5 до 8 полей, чтобы покрыть максимум типов данных.

Мне лично не нравится иметь таблицу, в которой (я точно знаю) для каждой строчки будут заполнены лишь 3 колонки из 7-10.

А если по каким-то причинам в середине проекта придется сменить тип данных? Все запросы переписывать? (хотя, согласен, это маловероятно :) )

---

*Ну и главное, последнее*...
Все очень сильно зависит от объемов данных и личных предпочтений разработчика :):):):):)

Comment: Я уточнил задачу в описании. Дело в том что эти параметры потом пойдут в приложение и будут конвертироваться в нужный тип. int в int, varchar в string и так далее. Поэтому хранить всё в varchar, на мой взгляд, не разумно как с стороны удобности использования так и со стороны объёма занимаемой памяти.